# how to run Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online command in Python On Windows server2016

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd

When I execute "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online" command in Windows2016 server powershell, the output is all fine, but when I execute with the Python script below,

```
cmd = os.popen("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online")
print(cmd.read())
```

the output is empty.

is there something wrong with my code?

I tried to exec ipconfig using this code, it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

My error comes from my ignorance of powershell. I regard powershell as cmd, so I directly use os.popen to call the command to be executed. In fact, you need to call powershell first to execute the command that needs to be executed, the following is an example：

```
import subprocess;
process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
result=process.communicate()[0]
```